# Where can I find datasets with labeled duplicate text documents?

Tags: data, training, text, classifier

I'm working on detecting duplicate text documents using a classifier. I am looking for training data - a corpus of text documents and corresponding metadata which lists out pairs of duplicate documents from the corpus. 
Where can I find such data?

Comment: i am also looking for the same dataset , share if you found any

Comment: I haven't found a dataset that I really like for this problem. I'm using the 20 Newsgroups data with some modifications. Not ideal.

Comment: @Minu Can you share how you are using 20 Newsgroups data? I do not find it helpful for this purpose. Any insight is very very appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of training a classifier, detecting duplicates may advantageously be done in a direct fashion: using a similarity metric like shingle signatures or a hashing/checksum function.

(A text to representation function F should preserve formal/meta elements that you already know to be identifiers or partial-identifiers, and it should also incorporate a compact representation of the content -- like sparse excerpts, checksum, or any other hashing key or canonized form. The comparison function G should then compare these text representations provided by F and define a similarity score.)

You'd still need an evaluation corpus, so looking for a corpus is still important. I don't know of any open one, but job-boards and academic databases contain lots of duplicates so you could start there.

Comment: I'm using a classifier on top of a similarity metric. I like to use the documents' metadata for duplicate detection and I'm using a classifier to make this distinction.

Comment: got it ! good luck for finding your corpora :)